# specify files for gradle task

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a task in gradle to replace token `VERSION` with specified project version in other properties file.

`war {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens:['VERSION': project.version])
}`

I have an issue: now gradle tries to find tokens in all files in `build` folder, but I want to specify only a few files, maybe just `index.jsp`.

smth like that:

`war {
    filter(ReplaceTokens('index.jsp'), tokens:[`VERSION`: project.version])
}`

But I don't know how to do this correctly.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found an answer:

`war {
    filesMatching('index.jsp') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: ['VERSION': project.version])
    }
}`